# Moodle Scorm Fullscreen Api

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, moodle, scorm

I want to know if it´s possible to use any fullscreen API to display a SCORM course in fullscreen in Moodle LMS?

I use the native HTML5 fullscreen. The fullscreen will work when I start the course outside of Moodle, but in Moodle it won't work.

Did anybody know my problem and maybe have a solution?

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that the issue you're experiencing is because with SCORM content has to open either in a pop-up or a frame. Presumably you've tried both of these and neither support full screen. The requirement to use a frame or pop-up is a limitation of SCORM so strict the answer to the question: "How can I go full screen with SCORM content?" is "You can't".

There are, however, two ways I can think of to work around this limitation:

1. **Have Moodle's SCORM player go full screen.** With this option, you customise the Moodle player itself to go full screen and then put your SCORM content within an iframe on that full screen view.
2. **Use an alternative tracking standard such as [Tin Can API](http://tincanapi.com?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=main?pmc=em-1) that supports launching in the same or a new window rather than a frame/pop-up.** You can get a [Tin Can plugin for Moodle](https://moodle.org/plugins/view/mod_tincanlaunch) and a [free LRS account for testing](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/tin-can-api-scorm-cloud/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=tincanapi_com&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=tin_can_scorm_cloud?pmc=em-1). There are [a number of other advantages to using Tin Can API instead of SCORM](http://tincanapi.com/scorm-vs-the-tin-can-api/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=tin-can-vs-scorm?pmc=em-1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use for launching an iframe into full screen.

`$('#ifrm')` is the selector for the iframe itself. You then set up an onclick handler to watch for a click on your full screen button or however you prefer to launch it. The else block is a fallback for IE 10 and under.

```
function launchFullScreen(element) {
if (element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
} else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
} else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) { // IE 11 API
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
} else {
    $source = $('#ifrm').attr('src');
    window.open($source, "", "fullscreen=no, resizable=1,toolbar=1,titlebar=yes"); // IE 10 and under workaround
    console.log("Fullscreen API is not supported");
}
```

}